# MongoDB random crashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crash-dumps

MongoDB crashes randomly every couple of days. That is very annoying.

Any idea what causes "got signal 15 (Terminated: 15), will terminate after current cmd ends"?

This is my log:

```
Fri Jan 25 17:48:40 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60264 #156 (13 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:29:31 [conn156] end connection 127.0.0.1:60264 (12 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 got signal 15 (Terminated: 15), will terminate after current cmd ends
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] now exiting
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 dbexit: 
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 7
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 8
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 9
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: final commit...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn153] end connection 127.0.0.1:59578 (11 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn150] end connection 127.0.0.1:59575 (11 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn152] end connection 127.0.0.1:59577 (11 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn151] end connection 127.0.0.1:59576 (11 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn76] end connection 127.0.0.1:51566 (7 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn77] end connection 127.0.0.1:51567 (6 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn155] end connection 127.0.0.1:59580 (5 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn79] end connection 127.0.0.1:51569 (4 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn78] end connection 127.0.0.1:51568 (3 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn154] end connection 127.0.0.1:59579 (2 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn74] end connection 127.0.0.1:51564 (1 connection now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] journalCleanup...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [conn75] end connection 127.0.0.1:51565 (0 connections now open)
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] removeJournalFiles
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 [interruptThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Jan 26 11:31:37 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7685?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel)

Comment: Signal 15 is the terminate signal so this looks to me like something is killing your mongod instance.  For example, you would get this output if you ran "kill <pid>" for the pid that your mongod instance has.

Comment: Same problem here...some suggestion?